# Attempting to change default MSI location for Chef-Chrome and nothing happening

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chef-infra

I wrote a wrapper for using the chef-chrome cookbook so I could point to an project-related AWS S3 bucket for the actual MSI files and when I run the "`chef-client -o recipe[get-chrome]`", it shows that it sees the internal cookbook, but nothing happens.

The plan was to have the wrapper change the default MSI file location (i.e. download only from S3 bucket, not outside world) as per the attributes/default.rb in the wrapper code, then continue the installation as per the original chef-chrome code (https://github.com/dhoer/chef-chrome).

```
default['chrome']['msi_64'] = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi'
```

Then run the basic installation command as per the baseline chrome cookbook already does. Am I doing something wrong or is my logic off?

Comment: did you 'include_recipe "chef-chrome"` in your wrapper cookbook ?

Comment: Yep. Did that. It didn't have an issue. It seems it might be a chef version issue that I need to resolve first though. Bah.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your wrapper recipe to `-o` instead of the original recipe or your custom values won't load.

Comment: Actually found one flaw and it's a bit annoying... FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookChefVersionMismatch: Cookbook 'chrome' version '3.0.0' depends on chef version [">= 12.14"], but the running chef version is 12.13.37.

Comment: You'll have to upgrade Chef then.